# No wireless connectivity on Dell Inspiron 1520

Tags: wireless, drivers, 12.10

I have just installed Ubuntu on a **Dell Inspiron 1520** that came pre installed with Windows Vista and i currently run both of the OS (I just choose when the computer starts up).

The wifi definitely works on the computer since i used it to download Ubuntu in the first place when I was using Vista. **The Network Manager says that I only have a 'Wired' Network and it doesn't have any other options to choose from.**

I connected the Laptop into a wired connection and downloaded the `Wicd Network Manager` but it had no effect either. From there I continued to go into `Software Sources` and installed the wireless drive but that had no effect either. So... What can I do?

Comment: I saw a problem with this when running the 12.10 Gnome remix version.  Could that be applicable in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Connect to your router via ehternet cable. It will be detected and
   configured automatically as auto eth0.

   Now you have internet connection.

   1. Click toe Ubuntu icon on the top left. It will open the "Dash" (Similar to Windows'Start Menu).
   2. On the Dash's search box, type `drivers` and you'll see an option called Adtional drivers.
   3. Your wireless driver may be listed. Select it and click on activate. It will be downloaded and installed.

Comment: Gosh, I can't get the editor to enumerate the steps correctly. There are 4 steps :)

Remeber to connect via ethernet in order to follow the procedure.